# Getting each from of a dataframe without column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a column to each row of a dataframe which includes a hash value of the row values.

I originally tried this:

```
df['hash'] = pd.Series((hash(tuple(row)) for _, row in df_to_hash.iterrows()))
```

However, when I ran this on two different DataFrames, I was encountering an issue when the column names didn't exactly match.

For example:

`DF1:`

```
  Name Age 
0 Tom   12
1 Pat   15
```

`DF1:`

```
  FirstName Age 
0 Tom       12
1 Pat       15
```

When I hashed the above DataFrames, row `0` in each dataframe had a different value due to the columns being different.

Is there a way I can has the row values only, excluding the columns?

I also tried this with no success:

```
df['hash'] = df_to_hash.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the underlying numpy array:

```
pd.Series((hash(tuple(row)) for row in df_to_hash.to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
0    2606281096150585092
1   -1842928179554038127
dtype: int64
```

You can also use [`pandas.util.hash_pandas_object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html) with `index=False`:

```
pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df_to_hash, index=False)
```

Output:

```
0    17445307237601047733
1    15658167368827391476
dtype: uint64
```